# Place grep result into variable

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I have a problem with bash script. I have a list of files in specific location. I have to take only a date from it and compare it with another date.

```
for i in *.gz; do
    echo $i | grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}'
done
```

The above is `grep`ing date from filenames correctly but only when I use `echo`. In another cases I have errors. I have tried:

`tmp=$(echo $i | grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}')`

Also not working. Any suggestions? I would be grateful for small help!

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What errors do you have?

Comment: add the list of files (your input) and what you expect (your output) otherwise is really hard to receive help

Comment: The `tmp=$(echo $i | grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}')` works fine for me.  When I do `echo $tmp`, I see the dates.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use `grep` at all here; use `bash`'s built-in regular-expression handling.

```
for i in *.gz; do
    [[ $i =~ [[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2} ]]
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
done
```

Comment: This one is working, but now how can I compare the dates I got(eg 2017-01-06) with current date -6 months?

Answer (score 0):

One way around it, could be  using stat command

```
for i in *.gz; do
    tmp=$(stat "$i" | awk '/Modify/ { print $2}' )
done
```

or if you want an array

```
declare -a tmp
tmp+=$(
        for i in *.gz; do
            stat "$i" | awk '/Modify/ { print $2}'
        done 
       )
```

The advantage is, that it is independent of the file names

edit:
I cannot comment on others answwers yet. So this is how you compare date

```
sixago=$(date --date='-6 month' +%s)
tmp=$(date --date="$tmp" +%s)

if [ "$tmp" -gt "$sixago" ];then
   ...
fi
```

Comment: The actual modification time doesn't necessarily correspond to the timestamp in the file name.

Comment: Right. Well, the `stat` command gives atime, ctime and mtime in the output. You can adjust the search string to `/Access/` or `/Change/`.

Comment: The timestamp in the file name probably reflects a time range covered by the data *in* the file, which could be independent of when the file was actually *produced*.

Comment: Thanks for the help to everyone, compering all the answers I have managed to solve the problem.